Postfix Issue: Cannot be able to send email
I am trying to configure my postfix so that my application can send email there seems to be no error, but I am not getting any email
Jun  4 03:05:46 ubuntu2004 postfix/pickup[109787]: 13CBB503034: uid=33 from=<service.bugzilla@samba.com.pk>
Jun  4 03:05:46 ubuntu2004 postfix/cleanup[109876]: 13CBB503034: message-id=<20240604070546.13CBB503034@mail.samba.com.pk>
Jun  4 03:05:46 ubuntu2004 postfix/qmgr[109788]: 13CBB503034: from=<service.bugzilla@samba.com.pk>, size=1786, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun  4 03:05:49 ubuntu2004 postfix/smtp[109878]: 13CBB503034: to=<babar.saeed@samba.com.pk>, relay=d173543a.ess.barracudanetworks.com[209.222.82.253]:25, delay=3, delays=0.04/0.01/2/0.96, >
Jun  4 03:05:49 ubuntu2004 postfix/cleanup[109876]: 160CA503035: message-id=<20240604070549.160CA503035@mail.samba.com.pk>
Jun  4 03:05:49 ubuntu2004 postfix/bounce[109879]: 13CBB503034: sender non-delivery notification: 160CA503035
Jun  4 03:05:49 ubuntu2004 postfix/qmgr[109788]: 160CA503035: from=<>, size=3998, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun  4 03:05:49 ubuntu2004 postfix/qmgr[109788]: 13CBB503034: removed
Jun  4 03:05:58 ubuntu2004 postfix/smtp[109878]: 160CA503035: to=<service.bugzilla@samba.com.pk>, relay=d173543a.ess.barracudanetworks.com[209.222.82.255]:25, delay=8.9, delays=0/0/5/4, ds>
Jun  4 03:05:58 ubuntu2004 postfix/qmgr[109788]: 160CA503035: removed

New logs as per mail log file
Jun  4 05:29:02 ubuntu2004 postfix/pickup[112993]: 3A0F6502F02: uid=33 from=<service.bugzilla@samba.com.pk>
Jun  4 05:29:02 ubuntu2004 postfix/cleanup[113400]: 3A0F6502F02: message-id=<20240604092902.3A0F6502F02@mail.samba.com.pk>
Jun  4 05:29:02 ubuntu2004 postfix/qmgr[112995]: 3A0F6502F02: from=<service.bugzilla@samba.com.pk>, size=1790, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun  4 05:29:05 ubuntu2004 postfix/smtp[113402]: 3A0F6502F02: to=<moeez.hussain@samba.com.pk>, relay=d173543a.ess.barracudanetworks.com[209.222.82.252]:25, delay=3.2, delays=0.11/0.01/2.1/>
Jun  4 05:29:05 ubuntu2004 postfix/cleanup[113400]: 6F3A3502F04: message-id=<20240604092905.6F3A3502F04@mail.samba.com.pk>
Jun  4 05:29:05 ubuntu2004 postfix/bounce[113405]: 3A0F6502F02: sender non-delivery notification: 6F3A3502F04
Jun  4 05:29:05 ubuntu2004 postfix/qmgr[112995]: 6F3A3502F04: from=<>, size=4031, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun  4 05:29:05 ubuntu2004 postfix/qmgr[112995]: 3A0F6502F02: removed
Jun  4 05:29:08 ubuntu2004 postfix/smtp[113402]: 6F3A3502F04: to=<service.bugzilla@samba.com.pk>, relay=d173543a.ess.barracudanetworks.com[209.222.82.252]:25, delay=2.7, delays=0/0/1.7/0.9>
Jun  4 05:29:08 ubuntu2004 postfix/qmgr[112995]: 6F3A3502F04: removed


Very confusing question please edit and fix. Title says can not send mail and question says can not receive mail. It looks like you have more details you have failed to share yet as well.

i am not getting any emails on my email address on which application is generating emails , as per logs i can not understand what is the issue
